Agricultural drainage design challenge in flat terrain using QGIS
I have a agricultural drainage challenge in QGIS.
I'm working on a project to design a micro-drainage network in a grain-growing area. The terrain is extremely flat (less than 1% slope), which hinders natural drainage. Currently, there are main drains installed every 60 meters, but depressions form between them where water accumulates, negatively affecting the crops.
My goal is to create an efficient micro-drainage network that connects these depressions to the main drains, ensuring proper surface water drainage and improving the productivity of the area.
I'm using a high-resolution DTM (3 cm GSD) and Whitebox tools in QGIS. My current workflow is as follows:

DepthInSink to identify depression;
FeaturePreservingSmoothing;
FillDepressions or BeatchDepressions;
D8 or Rho8 Pointer;
(D8 or Rho8) Flow Accumulation;
ExtractStreams;
RasterStreamsToVector;
Smoothing with other methods (Civil3D and AgroCAD)

The problem is removal of main drains. FillDepressions is removing some of the existing main drains, which causes problems in subsequent analysis.
How can I prevent this?
I've attached some screenshots to illustrate

The desired result.

The depressions identified with DepthInSink.

My current results.


